EPaper display driver schematic
I want to try to integrate a EPaper display into my circuit with the FPC24 connector displayed here: https://www.waveshare.com/product/displays/e-paper/epaper-2/2.66inch-e-paper-b.htm
Currently, I'm using a female header as a temporary solution. and will be integrated with an ESP32. Its just here for a reference with my current setup.
This is how my schematic looks so far, based on the schematic from waveshare:
https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/8/85/2.9inch_e-Paper_Schematic.pdf

As a novice in electronics design, I have some questions about EasyEDA:
In the original Waveshare schematic, NetLabels (GDR and RESE) are used without NetPorts. To prevent EasyEDA errors about incomplete nets, I added NetPorts. However, this seems to cause new issues.
Could you advise on the correct approach for this?
Thank you in advance for your help.

EasyEDA has a forum and user support. You pay for the service (indirectly when paying for PCBs), so you should expect to get help from them :)
